How can I add a Global:Custom text field through install file?
I am creating a view through an install file. The view is getting created and all the fields are added, except Global: Custom text one.
May someone please review the code and help with the correct values to use for this particular field?
$view_config = [
    'id' => 'application_listing',
    'label' => 'Application Listing',
    'base_table' => 'node_field_data',
    'display' => [
      'default' => [
        'display_plugin' => 'default',
        'id' => 'default',
        'display_title' => 'Master',
        'position' => 0,
        'display_options' => [
          'fields' => [
            'title' => [
              'id' => 'title',
              'table' => 'node_field_data',
              'field' => 'title',
              'label' => 'Company name',
              'alter' => ['word_boundary' => FALSE, 'ellipsis' => FALSE],
              'plugin_id' => 'field',
            ],
            'field_code' => [
              'id' => 'field_code',
              'table' => 'node__field_code',
              'field' => 'field_code',
              'label' => 'LEI code',
              'plugin_id' => 'field',
            ],
            'field_status' => [
              'id' => 'field_status',
              'table' => 'node__field_status',
              'field' => 'field_status',
              'label' => 'LEI status',
              'plugin_id' => 'field',
            ],
            'field_next_renewal_date' => [
              'id' => 'field_next_renewal_date',
              'table' => 'node__field_next_renewal_date',
              'field' => 'field_next_renewal_date',
              'label' => 'Next renewal date',
              'plugin_id' => 'field',
            ],
            'nid' => [
              'id' => 'nid',
              'table' => 'node_field_data',
              'field' => 'nid',
              'label' => 'Node ID',
              'plugin_id' => 'field',
            ],
            'custom_text' => [
              'id' => 'custom_text',
              'table' => 'views',
              'field' => 'custom_text',
              'label' => 'Custom text',
              'plugin_id' => 'field',
              'settings' => [
                'text' => 'Custom Static Text Here',
              ],
            ],
          ],
          'filters' => [
            'status' => [
              'id' => 'status',
              'table' => 'node_field_data',
              'field' => 'status',
              'value' => '1',
              'group' => 1,
              'expose' => [
                'operator' => '',
                'operator_limit_selection' => FALSE,
                'operator_list' => [],
              ],
              'plugin_id' => 'boolean',
              'entity_type' => 'node',
              'entity_field' => 'status',
            ],
            'type' => [
              'id' => 'type',
              'table' => 'node_field_data',
              'field' => 'type',
              'value' => [
                'application' => 'application',
              ],
              'entity_type' => 'node',
              'entity_field' => 'type',
              'plugin_id' => 'bundle',
              'group' => 1,
            ],
          ],
          'sorts' => [
            'created' => [
              'id' => 'created',
              'table' => 'node_field_data',
              'field' => 'created',
              'order' => 'DESC',
              'entity_type' => 'node',
              'entity_field' => 'created',
              'plugin_id' => 'date',
              'group' => 1,
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
      'page_1' => [
        'display_plugin' => 'page',
        'id' => 'page_1',
        'display_title' => 'Page',
        'position' => 1,
        'display_options' => [
          'path' => 'application-listing',
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ];

  $view = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('view')->create($view_config);
  $view->save();
}


You wouldn't. You would include it as a .yml config file to by installed on a site install. You can put it in a custom module config/install directory and it will be installed when the module is installed.
